# Terminal loop works for mac but not pc python

Tags: macos, shell

I have a terminal loop command which I use on mac:

```
for i in {1..30}; do python Rev1stRT.py A${i}F.txt FirstRevRtA${i}.txt; done
```

this works for a bunch files named `A1F.txt` `A2F.txt` `A3F.txt` etc etc
I have send the command for the student (she uses pc), but she gets the following error:

```
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:1 char:5
for <<<< i in {1..30}; do python Rev1stRT.py A${i}F.txt FirstRevRtA${i}.txt; done
CategoryInfo    : ParserError: (OpenParenToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId: MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

However, if she tries to run the same script as a single command (i.e., `python Rev1stRT.py A2F.txt FirstRevRtA2.txt`) everything works fine (which means that she has the data files and script file in the correct folder as I instructed)

UPDATE (functioning Powershell loop):

```
 $dirs = Get-ChildItem $directory | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $false} 

 foreach ($d in $dirs){ python script.py $d "${d}_output.txt";}`
```

Comment: is it possible that your student uses a shell whose syntax is different from yours?

Comment: I was trying to google possible differences between shell and terminal as well, but no luck :S

Comment: if you google for, e.g., `FullyQualifiedErrorId` ... is there a pattern in your results? do they invariably mention MS Windows' _PowerShell_? Do you expect that something that's OK on a Mac does work, w/o modifications, on  a MS Windows system?

Comment: yes, I have tried googling the error - no luck. Most of other examples are about the users not being able to run a single .py script or even launch python as such from Power shell and these are not the issues.
As far as I know the power shell and terminal commands should be identical...

Comment: Actually the small shell script part could easily be integrated into the Python program too, which should solve the problem with improved performance, since no new Python instances are started for each single iteration.

Comment: @guidot I agree, it would be easier and cleaner to use `os` module to do this in the program itself!

Answer (score 2):

Loops in Windows Powershell have a different syntax than `bash` which is the default shell for Terminal on Macs.

Assuming Python is installed and added to the `Path` environment variable, something like this would work:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 30; $i++) {
    python Rev1stRT.py "A$iF.txt" "FirstRevRtA$i.txt";
}
```

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx

Comment: yes, python was installed in that pc, because my student was able to run the script throughout all the 30 data files running them one by one, but the loop did not work.